# How to write Junit tests for this code with 100% code coverage?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, code-coverage

Junit tests for Spring Boot application.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might achieve this using JUnit and Mockito?

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public List<Student> getStudentDetails(String department) {

   List<Student> results = new LinkedList<String>();
   results =  jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE DEPARTMENT = ?", new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, department);
            preparedStatement.setFetchSize(10);
        }
    }, new ResultSetExtractor<List<Student>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Student> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
            List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Student student = new Student<>();
                student.setDepartment(rs.getString("NAME"));
                student.setName(rs.getString("DEPARTMENT"));
                students.add(student);
            }
            return students;
        }
    });
   return results      
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that you have is related to database and in my opinion it should be tested using some database. Usual practice is to use embedded database ( e.g. h2 ). People do it, since using unit tests it's not possible to check if query really works, since you don't actually run it. So I would combine integration and unit tests for testing of this class.

Unit test would be something like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class StubTest {

    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @InjectMocks
    Stub stub;

    @Test
    void whenExecuteQuery_thenExtractDataCorrectly() throws SQLException {
        //GIVEN
        ArgumentCaptor<PreparedStatementSetter> setterCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(PreparedStatementSetter.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<ResultSetExtractor> extractorCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ResultSetExtractor.class);
        //WHEN
        stub.getStudentDetails("TEST");
        //THEN
        verify(jdbcTemplate).query(anyString(), setterCaptor.capture(), extractorCaptor.capture());
        //AND
        PreparedStatementSetter setter = setterCaptor.getValue();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = Mockito.mock(PreparedStatement.class);
        setter.setValues(preparedStatement);
        verify(preparedStatement).setString(1, "TEST");
        verify(preparedStatement).setFetchSize(10);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(preparedStatement);
        //AND
        ResultSetExtractor extractor = extractorCaptor.getValue();
        ResultSet rs = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
        when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
        when(rs.getString(anyString())).thenReturn("TEST","name");
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(rs);
        List<Student> students = (List<Student>) extractor.extractData(rs);
        assertThat(students.get(0).getName()).isEqualTo("name");
        assertThat(students.get(0).getDepartment()).isEqualTo("TEST");
    }
}
```

Here I'm just capturing arguments with business logic that we send to `query` method. Then I run overridden methods of arguments and verify that they work as we expect.